# Jank when scrolling and adding data to ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Why does ListView.builder jank when I try to add data to it. Also, there is noticeable frame jumping when I scroll without applying much force. A single cell consists of a CachedNetworkImage and two Texts. I have tried removing shrinkWrap, adding cacheExtent and adding different kinds of Physics. I have tried preaching shaders and running in --release and --profile mode.

Is there anyone that knows how to solve this problem with ListViews generally.

Flutter version:

```
Flutter 2.12.0-4.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5c931b769b (2 weeks ago) • 2022-03-29 10:49:29 -0500
Engine • revision 486f4a749e
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-182.2.beta) • DevTools 2.11.1
```

I have tried switching channels to stable, but it is even worse there.

Comment: I suspect that you're running in debug mode, if so it's normal. The framework is doing loads of background stuff. Try running in release mode and see if same thing happens.

Comment: Try without the CachedNetworkImages. If the problem disappears it's their fault